# Windows phone 10 reopen app from background task

Tags: c#, windows-phone, background-task

Im having trouble with a customer request. We are developing an app for a mobile service provider, the app is showing the devices characteristics and prices on different packgages (devices that are on display in different stores). The request was to show the application (browser page with phone characteristics) when user puts the phone in a docking position. I can tell when the device is in docking position using accelerometer and a background task, I also fire a toast message when device docks. I found some answers saying it cant be done, but still Im a bit sceptical, that nothing can be done to redisplay the app if its not visible (set in AppSettings as a bool flag).

So my question is, can I activate/resume/redisplay the application if it is not in foreground mode from the background task?

I tried using `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-app://Page.xaml", UriKind.Absolute));` but it does not navigate to page.

Thank you for your answers.
B